# Перевод компьютера в спящий режим

Tags: python

Всем привет! Пытаюсь сделать питон код для перевода компьютера в "ждущий режим" (сон). (Windows)
Перерыл много вариантов, но нашёл только для перевода в режим гибернации.
Помогите, пожалуйста с кодом. Заранее спасибо! ☺

Comment: Гибернация — это и есть спящий режим

Comment: Это вроде немного другой режим, так как при запуске, компьютер загружается как при обычном запуске после выключения, а спящий режим загружается быстро. К тому же у меня 2 ос,  и при гибернации запускается выбор между ними, а в спящем режиме нет.

Comment: Значит вы путаете его с ждущим режимом (который иногда называют просто сном)

Comment: Возможно, подскажите, как его активировать.

Comment: В любом случае это зависит от операционной системы

Comment: операционка - Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перевод в спящий режим на разных ОС выполняется по разному, так что вы можете выполнить команду `os.system` для выполнения консольной команды и выбрать команду в зависимости от ОС пользователя. ОС пользователя можно определить с помощью функции `platform.system()`. Делается это следующим образом:

```py
import platform
import os

match platform.system():
    case "Linux":
        os.system("systemctl suspend")
    case "Darwin":  # MacOS
        os.system("pmset sleepnow")
    case "Windows":
        os.system("rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0")
    case "Java":
        raise NotImplementedError("Sleep command not implemented for Java")
    case "":
        raise ValueError("Can't determine operation system")
```

Я воспользовался [match-case statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#match-statements), но вы также можете использовать `if`, `elif`, `else`

UPD: Добавил команду для Windows